# Javascript.confirm() and Angularjs Karma e2e test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I have an **Angularjs** application that uses simple javascript confirm before executing some actions.

### Controller:

```
function TokenController($scope) {
  $scope.token = 'sampleToken';

  $scope.newToken = function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the token?") == true) {
      $scope.token = 'modifiedToken';
    }
  };
}
```

### View:

```
<div id="tokenDiv">
  Token:{{token}} <button ng-click="newToken()">New Token</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to have an end to end test to check the token is being replaced correctly in the view. How can I intercept the `javascript.confirm()` call so it doesn't stop the execution of the test?

### Test:

```
it('should be able to generate new token', function () {
   var oldValues = element('#tokenDiv').text();
   element('button[ng-click="newToken()"]').click(); // Here the javascript confirm box pops up.
   expect(element('#tokenDiv').text()).not.toBe(oldValues);
});
```

So far I've tried to redefine the `window.confirm` function but then the actual call complains that it is undefined.

I also wanted to set up a Jasmine spy on `window.confirm` but in the following syntax `spyOn(window, 'confirm');` it gives me an error saying you can not spy on `null`.

How would I go about making such test work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### E2E Testing

Please consult to this project:
https://github.com/katranci/Angular-E2E-Window-Dialog-Commands

### Unit Testing

If you create a service for the dialog boxes then you can mock that service in your unit test in order to make your code testable:

#### Controller

```
function TokenController($scope, modalDialog) {
  $scope.token = 'sampleToken';

  $scope.newToken = function() {
    if (modalDialog.confirm("Are you sure you want to change the token?") == true) {
      $scope.token = 'modifiedToken';
    }
  };
}
```

#### modalDialog service

```
yourApp.factory('modalDialog', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        confirm: function(message) {
            return $window.confirm(message);
        }
    }
}]);
```

#### modalDialogMock

```
function modalDialogMock() {
    this.confirmResult;

    this.confirm = function() {
        return this.confirmResult;
    }

    this.confirmTrue = function() {
        this.confirmResult = true;
    }

    this.confirmFalse = function() {
        this.confirmResult = false;
    }
}
```

#### Test

```
var scope;
var modalDialog;

beforeEach(module('yourApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    modalDialog = new modalDialogMock();
    var ctrl = $controller('TokenController', {$scope: scope, modalDialog: modalDialog});
}));

it('should be able to generate new token', function () {
   modalDialog.confirmTrue();

   scope.newToken();
   expect(scope.token).toBe('modifiedToken');
});
```

Answer (score 30):

Another option would be to directly create a spy and automatically return `true`:

```
//Jasmine 2.0
spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.callFake(function () {
     return true;
});

//Jasmine 1.3
spyOn(window, 'confirm').andCallFake(function () {
     return true;
});
```

Comment: This answer works great if you don't want to update your code to wrap around `window.confirm` calls.

Answer (score 7):

In unit tests you can mock the $window object like this:

Your test:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('myAppName');

    inject(function($rootScope, $injector) {
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var windowMock = { confirm: function(msg) { return true } }
        $controller('UsersCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $window: windowMock });
    });
});
```

Your controller:

```
myAppName.controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.delete = function() {
        var answer = $window.confirm('Delete?');
        if (answer) {
             // doing something
        }
    }
});
```