# How to add an confirmation window on ng-click Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a link with ng-click. I need a confirmation window on that click.

```
<h4><a href="" ng-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index);remove(favouriteData.data.result,$index)">Un-Favourite</a></h4>
```

currently it includes 2 functions. I have to execute this two functions only after confirmation. my two functions are defined in usercontroller.js.plz see code below

```
var userControllers = angular.module('userControllers', ['ui.bootstrap','gm']);
userControllers.controller('myProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $http, $location, $window, $timeout) {`  
$scope.makeUnfavourite=function(id,index){
    var indextoremove=index;
    var currentuserid=2;
    var favUserId=id;
    console.log(favUserId);
    var params = {
        currentuserid:2,
        favUserId:id
        };
       if(favUserId){
        $http.post($rootScope.STATIC_URL + 'users/makeUnFavourite', params).success(function(response){
            $scope.favHide=response;
            }).error(function(err){
            console.log("Error"+err);
        });
    }

};
$scope.remove = function(favourite,index){
    favourite.splice(index,1);
};
});
```

I have to execute makeUnfavourite() & remove() function on confirmation.I am  fresher in angular. Now I am working in a partially finished project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirmation dialog on ng-click - AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313576/confirmation-dialog-on-ng-click-angularjs)

Comment: Duplicate question

Comment: First of all, why you dont post all your code for best understanding? And, explain what you whant to achieve for better solutions.

Comment: I have a page with list of my favourite friends.Below each friend there is an option to mark that friend as unfavourite. So while clicking Un-Favourite button, I need a confirmation window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy, you have 2 functions

```
<a confirmed-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index)" ng-confirm-click="Confirm unfavorite?">Un-Favourite</a>
```

Now you could call `$scope.remove`function inside makeUnFavorite, or, inside confirmed-click, like this:

```
<a confirmed-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index);remove(favouriteData.data.result,$index);" ng-confirm-click="Confirm unfavorite?">Un-Favourite</a>
```

---

I prefer first solution. Complete code:

Controller

```
var userControllers = angular.module('userControllers', ['ui.bootstrap','gm']);
userControllers.controller('myProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $http, $location, $window, $timeout) {`  
$scope.makeUnfavourite=function(id,index,favourite){
    var indextoremove=index;
    var currentuserid=2;
    var favUserId=id;
    console.log(favUserId);
    var params = {
        currentuserid:2,
        favUserId:id
        };
       if(favUserId){
        $http.post($rootScope.STATIC_URL + 'users/makeUnFavourite', params).success(function(response){
            $scope.favHide=response;
            //here we call the remove function, always inside the $http response for not having async issues
            $scope.remove(favourite,index);
            }).error(function(err){
            console.log("Error"+err);
        });
    }


};
$scope.remove = function(favourite,index){
    favourite.splice(index,1);
};
});
```

HTML

```
<a confirmed-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index,favouriteData.data.result)" ng-confirm-click="Confirm unfavorite?">Un-Favourite</a>
```

**EDIT**

One more thing, it would be better if you use on $http.post this structure:

```
$http.post($rootScope.STATIC_URL + 'users/makeUnFavourite').then(function(response){
     //Ok response stuff
}, function(error){
     //Error response stuff
});
```

Comment: Working fine.easy method without using directives. This is what i expect. Thanks

Comment: Mark Answer as correct for any other user (you could vote too if it helped you)

Comment: Can we call a function on click of "Cancel" in the confirmation dialog ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use ng-confirm-click, like this:

```
<h4><a href="" confirmed-click="confirmedAction()" ng-confirm-click="Do you confirm?">Un-Favourite</a></h4>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3lcKYStyELLxF7S25Cn4?p=preview)

**UPDATE**:
For angular directives, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)...

**UPDATE 2**:
I see. You could simply do:

```
$scope.confirmedAction = function() {
    makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId, $index);
    remove(favouriteData.data.result, $index);
};
```

Comment: in my application I have written functons in controller as like below: $scope.getAllFavourite=function(id){-------};. How to write the above functions (app.directive) like i wrote?. I am new to angular

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand... Do you want to write a directive? See my update to answer... But to answer to your question you can just *use* angular.js built-in directive `ng-confirm-click`...

Comment: but browser shows error that the above two functions are undefined?

Comment: Marco. if I place the two functions inside $scope.confirmedAction() method, the application did not execute that functios.But when i give like this, it works fine : makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index);remove(favouriteData.data.result,$index);. thanks . But ur directive is working fine

Comment: @MarcoS, Is there any possibility here to disable system generated the top line which says: **An Embedded page at run.plunk.co says**.

Answer (score 0):

> ng-click return confirm 100% works
>
> in html file call delete_plot() function

```
<i class="fa fa-trash delete-plot" ng-click="delete_plot()"></i>
```

> Add this to your controller

```
 $scope.delete_plot = function(){
        check = confirm("Are you sure to delete this plot?")
        if(check){
            console.log("yes, OK pressed")
        }else{
            console.log("No, cancel pressed")

        }
    }
```