# angularjs: confirmation dialog not working properly

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to create a confirmation dialog in angularjs, i found an answered question about that in stackoverflow 
[Confirmation dialog on ng-click - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313576/confirmation-dialog-on-ng-click-angularjs)
i tried it as it is answered but when i click cancel it works as if i clicked OK is the answer wrong or should i add something else

```
    <button type="button"  ng-click="updateData()" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure?">
            Update
    </button>
```

directive

```
    app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved using your same directive, but, instead of using `ng-click` for the final action on user confirmation, I did use the attribute `confirmed-click` with the final action as it's value.

html:

```
<button confirmed-click="confirm()" ng-confirm-click="Are you really sure?">Update</button>
```

---

directive:

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function() {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if (window.confirm(msg)) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

---

See this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/7b3jUJkdV8E94etuFEc0?p=preview).

Comment: the point is that the `confirm()` action should be called by the directive code, aftre the user has confirmend her choice.... With `ng-click`, the action is called on the first click...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is write. Just Change "ng-click" to "confirmed-click" and it will work fine

```
<button type="button"  confirmed-click="updateData()" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure?">
            Update
    </button>
```

Just check plank [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wxqTpT2iHnS26elwtW7e?p=preview)