# Why does my directive fail without errors?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This directive:

```
angular.module('WizmoApp', [])
    .directive('confirmClick', function() {
        return {

                priority: -1,
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind('click', function(e){
                        var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
                        // confirm() requires jQuery
                        if(message && !confirm(message)){
                            //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            //e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                }
        };
    });
```

, which I'm trying to transcribe from here:
[Confirmation dialog on ng-click - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313576/confirmation-dialog-on-ng-click-angularjs)
is enough to bring my app to a screeching halt.
No display on-screen, no js errors, no nothing, just a blank sacreen.

This is how I'm using it:

```
<tr class="" 
    ng-repeat="package in adminManifestVm.Manifest | orderBy:'Id' track by $index"  
    ng-click="adminManifestVm.debinPackage(package.Id);" 
    ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to debin this?">
```

No idea how to debug a directive, let alone write one.

[ EDIT ]
I just noticed that, in the example, the directive is actually called **ngConfirmClick**. Changed it, but makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

you are using it wrong

```
<tr class="" 
ng-repeat="package in adminManifestVm.Manifest | orderBy:'Id' track by $index"  
ng-click="adminManifestVm.debinPackage(package.Id);" 
confirm-click val="Are you sure you want to debin this?">
```

and in your directive add scope

```
angular.module('WizmoApp', [])
.directive('confirmClick', function() {
    return {
            scope:{
              val: '='
             },
            priority: -1,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.bind('click', function(e){
                    var message = val;
                    // confirm() requires jQuery
                    if(message && !confirm(message)){
                        //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        //e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah. Serves me right for copying a snippet that was not vetted as correct.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as-is. I get a 'unexpected string' at val '=' or 'val is undefined'. I'll fiddle with it.

Comment: I assumed it was a missing ':' but it isn't.

Comment: Gotta be attrs.val

Answer (score 0):

That solution is not working. This error makes no sense:

> Syntax Error: Token 'Package' is an unexpected token at column 6 of
>   the expression [Move Package back to Pile?] starting at [Package back
>   to Pile?].

This is how I've implemented it:

Directive:

```
(function(){
angular
    .module('WizmoApp')
    .directive('confirmClick', function () {
        return {
            priority: -1,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.bind('click', function(e){
                    var message = attrs.val;
                    // confirm() requires jQuery
                    if(message && !confirm(message)){
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
});
})();
```

View:

```
<tr class="" 
    ng-repeat="package in adminManifestVm.Manifest | orderBy:'Id' track by $index"  
    ng-click="adminManifestVm.debinPackage(package.Id);" 
    confirm-click 
    val="Move Package back to Pile?">
```