# Delete function not working properly in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs

this is my code for delete particular row in table on form in angular.

its working but not properly. Problem is when i click on delete button
only pop ups comes.after that nothing happens. when i refresh my page
on refresh that particular row deletes.

So everytime i have to refresh
page to see delete works or not?  How to solve this issue so i dont
have to refresh my page evertytime after delete something.

```
<a ng-click="deleteInfo(detail)" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure
 you wish to delete this Record?');">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your confirm alert inside the ng-click function.

```
scope.deleteInfo = function(detail){
  $ngBootbox.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Record?')
 .then(function() {
     //either you can reload window or delete the particular ng-model or whatever
  },
   function() {
   }); 
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because only your onclick triggered in this scenario, you should use a custom directive to achieve this, like :

```
module.directive( "mwConfirmClick", [
  function( ) {
    return {
      priority: -1,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: { confirmFunction: "&mwConfirmClick" },
      link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
        element.bind( 'click', function( e ){
          // message defaults to "Are you sure?"
          var message = attrs.mwConfirmClickMessage ? attrs.mwConfirmClickMessage : "Are you sure?";
          // confirm() requires jQuery
          if( confirm( message ) ) {
            scope.confirmFunction();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

please refere to [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313576/confirmation-dialog-on-ng-click-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Use sweet-alert for confirmation except "onclick" method

> http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/